# identity involving spectral functions

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, real-analysis, matrices, operator-theory

Let $A$ be any compact operator and let $A^*$ denote its adjoint. Let $f$ be a spectral function. Then is the following true :

$$ A^* f(AA^*) = f(A^* A) A^*$$

Comment: If $f$ is a polynomial, then the result is true (doesn't need compactness); this boils down to  $A^*(AA^*)^n = (A^*A)^n A^*$, which follows because the strings are equal. Then the result holds if $f(B)$ is a uniform  limit of polynomials in $B$ (for BLTs), and probably more generally for strong limits.

Comment: What does spectral function mean?

Comment: @DavidHandelman I think your argument holds for any bounded linear operator $A$ on a Hilbert space, and $f$ a bounded Borel function on $[0,\infty)$.